# making API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call Youtube API but I keep getting this error. what I'm doing wrong?

```js
import axios from "axios";

const KEY = "<API_KEY>"

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3',
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResult: 10,
    key: KEY
})
```

this is the error message

> localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 403', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Consider your credential exposed.  Please regenerate a new key and consider refraining from posting it in the future.

Comment: Hi, you should hide your API key, also 403 error means your key is not valid or request is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

403 means Forbidden, it is either your API key issue or you are not following the steps to hit API properly. Please double check the API key and follow this documentation for step by step process. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#intro